# Second page of list of figures: spacing too large

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, line-spacing

I have a list of figures which spans multiple pages. The first page is looking just fine but when it continues on to the next page, the space between the lines is more than tripled compared to the previous page.

See the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of the line space bug]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\raggedbottom`, instead of `\flushbottom`. The latter will try to stretch the height of the text to get a full page. After the TOC, you can use `\flushbottom` again.

Comment: Thank you for that! Worked just as you said. However, I found out that my colleague was using the wrong hack (`minipage`) to prevent page break after the `Fist of Figures`.