# Should I leave LaTeX decide the vertical height of the space above a text paragraph?

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, typography

In my document, above a text paragraph, there are objects of many possibilities: `\end{figure}`, `\end{align*}`, `$$`, `\end{itemize}`,  `end{enumerate}`, etc... It seems that visually on the final pdf, it does not leave space of same height before the text paragraph. So I have to try several `\\` or add black line in my `.tex` to get a consistent layout...

This manual adjustment confuses me, is there any elegant way to determine the space of certain height? What do you put usually after a `end{...}` before a text paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you don't use `\raggedbottom` but `\flushbottom` (which depending on your document class is enabled by default). The effect is, that TeX adjusts the spaces between your paragraphs and environments.

Also read this question:
[Second page of list of figures: spacing too large](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18038/second-page-of-list-of-figures-spacing-too-large)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, where should I put this `\raggedbottom`?

Comment: Put it before `\begin{document}` and it will impact your whole document.

Answer (score 3):

There are no "text paragraphs", only paragraphs and items possibly included in paragraphs. Although it may be surprising at first, displayed equations (`align`) and lists (`itemize`, `enumerate`) can be a part of paragraphs. (They may also start and/or end a paragraph -- this is denoted by adding a blank line in the source.) And floats (`figure`), though not included in paragraphs, do not split the text before and after them into separate paragraphs -- floats are simply not part of the running text.

So yes, don't add random line breaks to create a layout you perceive as "consistent". Let LaTeX deal with vertical spacing.